# Using PlotRange to cut off outlying points

Tags: plotting, documentation

In the [documentation for PlotRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html), there is the following line:

- If a particular minimum or maximum is specified as `{Automatic, α}`, this means that the range should in effect be cut off beyond a fraction $α$ of points in the plot. When smooth curves or surfaces are plotted, the measure of points is based on projected length or area.

I would like to use this option to cut off, say, 10 percent of the points in a `ListPlot`. I am aware that `ListPlot`'s default `PlotRange -> Automatic` option does cut off a fraction of the points, but I would like to control how many points are cut off. However, whenever I try to use the pair `{Automatic, 0.1}` in place of a coordinate's maximum or minimum I get the following error:

```
Value of option PlotRange -> (*PlotRange specification*) is not All, Full, Automatic, 
a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications.
```

Am I misunderstanding or incorrectly applying the documentation here, or is there an actual error in the documentation here?

Comment: I'm just as confused by the docs as you are. It's either a bug or bad wording.

Comment: I agree: I had not noticed that part of the documentation before, but I do interpret it as OP did. I have been playing around with it a bit, but I can't seem to do anything more than setting explicit `PlotRange`s when using the suggested syntax... Strange.

Comment: is *is* bad wording regardless of whether its also bug ( or an abandoned feature perhaps? ).  Liam, can you include an example of the actual syntax you tried that produces that error in the question.

Comment: Here's an example of syntax which gave the aforementioned error: `ListPlot[Table[{n, Exp[-n] Sin[n]}, {n, 1, 10}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {{Automatic, 0.1}, {Automatic, 0.2}}}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata = Table[RandomReal[], {100}]
```

If you want to cut off the top .1 and bottom .1 of the data, just use the proper quantiles:

```
ListPlot[mydata,
 PlotRange -> Quantile[mydata, {.1, .9}]]
```

or interactively...

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[mydata,
  PlotRange -> Quantile[mydata, {i, 1 - i}]
  ], {i, 0, .5}]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your first option chooses an automatic value for the minimum y value, and sets 0.5 as the maximum value...
And your second option clips the data from `(ymin,ymax)` to `(ymin+0.3,ymax-0.3)` instead of cutting off 30% of the points. But thank you!